# Read Only field in View

Tags: 2013, datasheet, read-only

We migrated a List with a field from 2010 where it was Read Only in Datasheet view. But in 2013 the Enhanced Rich Text field is now Editable.

In 2013, Is there a way to make the Enhanced Text Field Read-Only in Data Sheet view? Or alternatively, hiding it once it is in Edit / Datasheet view

Answer (score 0):

It can be done adding a `JSLink` (javascript file) to the filed.

A similar question has been answered here with an example:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fdba0940-2ebd-49a8-a1a5-41ba083accf0/prevent-editting-a-field-inside-the-quick-edit-using-jslink?forum=sharepointdevelopment